# How to fix bug install package FbF/Laravel-Youtube in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, youtube-api

i using package to upload videos to a YouTube channel in my project.

https://github.com/FbF/Laravel-Youtube

but i cant not install it.
can anyone help me, please!

this is required in  my file composer.json

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "jenssegers/date": "^3.2",
    "vinkla/vimeo": "^3.2",
    "fbf/laravel-youtube": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
```

i search google they said change

```
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": false,
```

to

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

but it's still not working :( . it's show error

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for fbf/laravel-youtube dev-master -> satisfiable   by     fbf/laravel-youtube[dev-master].
- fbf/laravel-youtube dev-master requires google/apiclient dev-master -> satisfiable by google/apiclient[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Comment: Try `"minimum-stability": "dev"`
`"prefer-stable": false,`

Comment: it still not working :(